# Guitar D9 without 3rd and 7th?

Tags: chord-theory

I've seen D9 on a guitar expressed as `D A D2 E2 A2`.
So I see no 3rd and no 7th. I've seen some topics talking abouth 12th and voicing, but still have no idea what that is all about and how it works.

Could someone enlighten me, please?

The chord tab as played:

```
e|-5- (A)12th
b|-5- (E)9th
G|-7- (D)8th
D|-7- (A)5th
A|-5- (D)1st
E|-x-
```

Comment: I haven't seen the talk about 12ths and voicing, but that's a Dsus2. It would fit in fine if someone else in the band is playing a *complete* D9, but as you say, it has no 3rd or 7th. And there may be no band!

Comment: Where did you see this?

Answer (score 2):

The notes you list wouldn't be WRONG to play over a D9 harmony.  But they are insufficient, in themselves, to establish D9.

This happens all the time in music.  A chord symbol can't tell the whole story.

Answer (score 1):

That's no D9. The notes which make up D9 are D, F♯, A, C and E. With only D A and E, at best it could be called Dsus2. It won't even be D add9, as there would need to be F♯. D sus9 is a faint possibility, with the E so high in the mix.

To be a 9th chord needs the 7th (of some sort) to also be present. It's not. And without a third, and more description, it can't be D9, Dmaj9 or Dm9.